# Php Google Drive Api v3 - connection problem (quickstart)

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I am trying to implement this code as its written in here:

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php

I run my php file in command line, it throws and url in command line and i open it in my browser, i log in my account and i allow quickstart etc.
And then it throws this error in my homepage:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: This application must be run on the command line. in C:\xampp\htdocs\upload-project\upload.php:10 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\upload-project\index.php(18): include() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\upload-project\upload.php on line 10

I don't understand, I already run my php file in command line and i open the link in my browser. What is wrong with this code?

```
 <?php

    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    
    if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
        throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns an authorized API client.
     * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
     */
    function getClient()
    {
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName('Google Drive API PHP Quickstart');
        $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);
        $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
        $client->setAccessType('offline');
        $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');
    
        // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
        // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
        // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
        // time.
        $tokenPath = 'token.json';
        if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
            $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
        }
    
        // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
        if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
            if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
                $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
            } else {
                // Request authorization from the user.
                $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
                printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
                print 'Enter verification code: ';
                $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));
    
                // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
                $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
                $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    
                // Check to see if there was an error.
                if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                    throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
                }
            }
            // Save the token to a file.
            if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
                mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
            }
            file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
        }
        return $client;
    }
    
    
    // Get the API client and construct the service object.
    $client = getClient();
    $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
    
    // Print the names and IDs for up to 10 files.
    $optParams = array(
      'pageSize' => 10,
      'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)'
    );
    $results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);
    
    if (count($results->getFiles()) == 0) {
        print "No files found.\n";
    } else {
        print "Files:\n";
        foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {
            printf("%s (%s)\n", $file->getName(), $file->getId());
        }
    }
```

Help please... I couldn't fix it.

Comment: to run your application command line do the following from the comand line "php upload.php"

Comment: @DaImTo hey! I run my php file by typing "php upload.php", but it still keeps throwing that error in my localhost.

Comment: @DaImTo , i checked my Url and it is like `http://localhost/upload-project/?code=4/1gFDUNPXSVR42FoafUCikHrz5TKW5YZcMYc1Vp9XixuiTOShM6wGdjlqtgjeoDC5z84HP4k7HbpBlSBDUToJDg4&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` 
I think my token is `4/1gFDUNPXSVR42FoafUCikHrz5TKW5YZcMYc1Vp9XixuiTOShM6wGdjlqtgjeoDC5z84HP4k7HbpBlSBDUToJDg4` but it doesnt accept. It throws this in terminal :
`Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Invalid token format`

Comment: How are you retrieving this URL: `http://localhost/upload-project/?code=4/1gFDUNPXSVR42FoafUCikHrz5TKW5YZcMYc1Vp9XixuiTOShM6wGdjlqtgjeoDC5z84HP4k7HbpBlSBDUToJDg4&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`? Because the scope is not correct, it should be `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly` as in your code.

Comment: @Alessandro I changed scopes a little bit after I couldn't fix. But it gives the same error even though i write `DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY` I just couldn't auth my account :(

Comment: Do you confirm that you comply with all the 3 prerequisites listed in the quickstart [webpage](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php)?